# Can You Use a Prepaid Gift Card Like Debit,Credit ( MasterCard or Visa ) To Buy Vbucks On Fortnite PC?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Ok so I'm wondering if it's possible to buy vbucks with a prepaid gift card like vanilla etc. So that I can buy vbucks myself and I don't have to ask others to buy it for me and I have to pay them. If I am able to use a prepaid gift card please comment or respond back with ones I could use and pick up at my local rite aid!.

Comment: Prepaid cards are functionally the same as a debit/credit card as far as I know. No reason they wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you link it to a [Paypal](https://www.paypal.com) account.